# Flutter: VideoPlayerController.asset does not play specified video

Tags: flutter

I am trying to play a video. I have added the necessary permissions.

I am using Android so I added this after :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Pubspec:

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

Code initializing controller:

```
_controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/video_1.mp4");
```

When I try with network urls (videos from the internet), it works just fine. I think something is wrong with specifying the video I want.

| Where I put my video | What I see on emulator |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

This is the full code: https://pastebin.com/32BVzBmM. It's copied from the Flutter VideoPlayer documentation example, the only thing changed being the one line above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your assets import is incorrect, make sure you have 2 spaces difference between the "assets:" and asset name like this:

```
assets:
  - assets/ // <- this should work
    - assets/ // <- this will not work
```

Don't forget to kill the app, run flutter clean && flutter pub get before running the app